# Process memory read

Tags: python, ctypes

I want to read the memory of the process and find certain values there. I do this because I am writing an anti-cheat for my server that will run on a person's PC. I know that python is not the best programming language for such things, but I want to implement it in python.

Can someone maybe sand code, that will detect this. I've been trying to do this for about 2 weeks

I tried this, but it won't work

```py
import ctypes

PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400
PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010
MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000
MEM_RESERVE = 0x2000
PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04
MAX_PATH = 260

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

class MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('BaseAddress', ctypes.c_void_p),
                ('AllocationBase', ctypes.c_void_p),
                ('AllocationProtect', ctypes.c_ulong),
                ('RegionSize', ctypes.c_size_t),
                ('State', ctypes.c_ulong),
                ('Protect', ctypes.c_ulong),
                ('Type', ctypes.c_ulong)]

def find_exechack(process_name):
    # Get a handle to each process with the specified name
    process_ids = []
    snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(0x2, 0)
    if snapshot != -1:
        entry = ctypes.Structure()
        entry.dwSize = ctypes.sizeof(entry)
        if kernel32.Process32First(snapshot, ctypes.byref(entry)):
            while True:
                if entry.szExeFile.decode() == process_name:
                    process_ids.append(entry.th32ProcessID)
                if not kernel32.Process32Next(snapshot, ctypes.byref(entry)):
                    break
    kernel32.CloseHandle(snapshot)

    # Search each process's memory for the exechack.cc string
    for pid in process_ids:
        process_handle = kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, False, pid)
        if process_handle == 0:
            continue

        address = ctypes.c_void_p()
        while True:
            mbi = MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION()
            result = kernel32.VirtualQueryEx(process_handle, address, ctypes.byref(mbi), ctypes.sizeof(mbi))
            if result == 0:
                break

            if mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT and mbi.Protect & PAGE_READWRITE and mbi.RegionSize > 0:
                buffer = (ctypes.c_char * mbi.RegionSize)()
                bytes_read = ctypes.c_size_t()
                if kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(process_handle, mbi.BaseAddress, ctypes.byref(buffer), mbi.RegionSize, ctypes.byref(bytes_read)):
                    # Search the buffer for the exechack.cc string
                    if b'exechack.cc' in buffer[:bytes_read.value]:
                        print(f"Found exechack.cc in process {pid}")
                        break

            address.value += mbi.RegionSize

        kernel32.CloseHandle(process_handle)
```

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code didn't have the `PROCESSENTRY32` structure defined and it is always a good idea to fully define `.argtypes` and `.restype` precisely for every function called by `ctypes`.

The code below works for my Notepad++ test case using a string I found in the binary:

```py
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.wintypes as w

PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400
PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010
MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000
MEM_RESERVE = 0x2000
PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04
MAX_PATH = 260
TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = 0x2
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = w.HANDLE(-1).value # 0xffffffff on 32-bit
                                          # 0xffffffffffffffff on 64-bit
SIZE_T = ct.c_size_t
ULONG_PTR = w.WPARAM  # WPARAM is ULONG on 32-bit and ULONGLONG on 64-bit.

class PROCESSENTRY32(ct.Structure):

    _fields_ = (('dwSize', w.DWORD),
                ('cntUsage', w.DWORD),
                ('th32ProcessID', w.DWORD),
                ('th32DefaultHeapID', ULONG_PTR),
                ('th32ModuleID', w.DWORD),
                ('cntThreads', w.DWORD),
                ('th32ParentProcessID', w.DWORD),
                ('pcPriClassBase', w.LONG),
                ('dwFlags', w.DWORD),
                ('szExeFile', w.CHAR * MAX_PATH))

    # Allow this structure to print itself
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'PROCESSENTRY32(dwSize={self.dwSize}, ' \
                              f'cntUsage={self.cntUsage}, ' \
                              f'th32ProcessID={self.th32ProcessID:#x}, ' \
                              f'th32DefaultHeapID={self.th32DefaultHeapID:#x}, ' \
                              f'th32ModuleID={self.th32ModuleID:#x}, ' \
                              f'cntThreads={self.cntThreads}, ' \
                              f'th32ParentProcessID={self.th32ParentProcessID:#x}, ' \
                              f'dwFlags={self.dwFlags:#x}, ' \
                              f'szExeFile={self.szExeFile})'

PPROCESSENTRY32 = ct.POINTER(PROCESSENTRY32)

class MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION(ct.Structure):

    _fields_ = (("BaseAddress", w.LPVOID),
                ("AllocationBase", w.LPVOID),
                ("AllocationProtect", w.DWORD),
                ("PartitionId", w.WORD),
                ("RegionSize", SIZE_T),
                ("State", w.DWORD),
                ("Protect", w.DWORD),
                ("Type", w.DWORD))

    # Allow this structure to print itself
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION(BaseAddress={self.BaseAddress if self.BaseAddress is not None else 0:#x}, ' \
                                        f'AllocationBase={self.AllocationBase if self.AllocationBase is not None else 0:#x}, ' \
                                        f'AllocationProtect={self.AllocationProtect:#x}, ' \
                                        f'PartitionId={self.PartitionId:#x}, ' \
                                        f'RegionSize={self.RegionSize:#x}, ' \
                                        f'State={self.State:#x}, ' \
                                        f'Protect={self.Protect:#x}, ' \
                                        f'Type={self.Type:#x})'

PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION = ct.POINTER(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)

k32 = ct.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
OpenProcess = k32.OpenProcess
OpenProcess.argtypes = w.DWORD, w.BOOL, w.DWORD
OpenProcess.restype = w.HANDLE

ReadProcessMemory = k32.ReadProcessMemory
ReadProcessMemory.argtypes = w.HANDLE, w.LPCVOID, w.LPVOID, ct.c_size_t, ct.POINTER(ct.c_size_t)
ReadProcessMemory.restype = w.BOOL

CloseHandle = k32.CloseHandle
CloseHandle.argtypes = w.HANDLE,
CloseHandle.restype = w.BOOL

VirtualQueryEx = k32.VirtualQueryEx
VirtualQueryEx.argtypes = w.HANDLE, w.LPCVOID, PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION, SIZE_T
VirtualQueryEx.restype = SIZE_T

CreateToolhelp32Snapshot = k32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.argtypes = w.DWORD, w.DWORD
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.restype = w.HANDLE

Process32First = k32.Process32First
Process32First.argtypes = w.HANDLE, PPROCESSENTRY32
Process32First.restype = w.BOOL

Process32Next = k32.Process32Next
Process32Next.argtypes = w.HANDLE, PPROCESSENTRY32
Process32Next.restype = w.BOOL

def find_bytes(process_name, bytes_value):
    # Get a handle to each process with the specified name
    process_ids = []
    snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0)
    if snapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
        entry = PROCESSENTRY32()
        entry.dwSize = ct.sizeof(entry)
        if Process32First(snapshot, ct.byref(entry)):
            while True:
                if entry.szExeFile.decode() == process_name:
                    process_ids.append(entry.th32ProcessID)
                if not Process32Next(snapshot, ct.byref(entry)):
                    break
        CloseHandle(snapshot)

    for pid in process_ids:
        process_handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, False, pid)
        if process_handle == 0:
            continue

        address = 0
        while True:
            mbi = MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION()
            result = VirtualQueryEx(process_handle, address, ct.byref(mbi), ct.sizeof(mbi))
            if not result:
                break

            if mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT and mbi.RegionSize > 0:
                buffer = ct.create_string_buffer(mbi.RegionSize)
                bytes_read = SIZE_T()
                if ReadProcessMemory(process_handle, mbi.BaseAddress, buffer, mbi.RegionSize, ct.byref(bytes_read)):
                    # Search the buffer for the exechack.cc string
                    if bytes_value in buffer[:bytes_read.value]:
                        print(f"Found in process {pid}")
                        break

            address += mbi.RegionSize

        CloseHandle(process_handle)

find_bytes('notepad++.exe', 'Linux'.encode('utf-16le'))
```

Comment: @Stanislav Are you kidding?  Change the last line. This code is generic.  I don’t have your target exe to test it against.

Comment: @MarkTolonen – I tested your solution by writing a word ‘testing’ into one of the Notepad++ windows and then running your code (changed the string accordingly in your code). It could not be found. What could be the reason? What regions of memory does you code search?

Comment: @miroxlav It searches all commited pages of memory in the process.  What *specifically* did you search for?  It's finding any strings I search for, but you have to consider the encoding. `b'testing'` should work.  The `'Linux'.encode('utf-16le')` appears as the bytes `4c 00 69 00 6e 00 75 00 78 00` in memory and was just a string I found in the binary, not text in a document.